# Elasticsearch 7.9 CCR changing the number of replicas on the leader index is not replicated by the follower index

Tags: java, elasticsearch, deployment, replication, ccr

I have an issue/question

I have 2 es clusters. Cross cluster replication is configured.
After reading replication mechanism from [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/xpack-ccr.html) I still have few questions.

1. What is the "**some updates**" in below quote? And what is "**as needed**"??? This is no clear.

> The follower index automatically retrieves some updates applied to the leader index, while other updates are retrieved as needed

2. Right after this I see another quote from which I can't understand how I can change replicas on leader so as it will replicated on follower? Is it possible at all?

> For example, changing the number of replicas on the leader index is not replicated by the follower index, so that setting might not be retrieved.

3. Next quote. How I can understand what is the static and what is the dynamic properties.

> If you apply a non-dynamic settings change to the leader index that is
> needed by the follower index, the follower index closes itself,
> applies the settings update, and then re-opens itself. The follower
> index is unavailable for reads and cannot replicate writes during this
> cycle.

4. Num_of_replicas is it non-dynamic property? If yes why it is not updating it at the follower site as said in previous quote. And how I could get list of such not updatable parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of questions in a single question , But let me try to answer all of them.

1. What are the `some updates` in the below quote? And what is `as needed`??? This is no clear.

***Answer: Updates which are not required for the `read operation(follower serve only read aka search requests)` on the follower index, will not be updated unless its required, for example, you update the mapping and add another field in your index, but unless your search query include that field, it might not be required to update this mapping on follower index. so as and when you required they pull the changes from the leader index.***

2. Right after this I see another quote from which I can't understand how I can change replicas on the leader so as it will be replicated on followers? Is it possible at all?

***Answer: As replicas are used for high availability, and you are already using cross-cluster replication, so when you again change the replica on leader index, it doesn't make sense to apply them on follower index, but if you delete all replica shards(Manually) than it might fetch the settings from leader index, you can try this yourself and my guess that time it will fetch the settings and apply it.***

3. Next quote. How I can understand what is the static and what is the dynamic properties.

***Answer: You can have a look at [index module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#index-modules-settings) which explains the difference and list all static and dynamic settings of the index.***

4. Num_of_replicas is it a non-dynamic property? If yes why it is not updating at the follower site as said in the previous quote. And how I could get a list of such not updatable parameters.

***Answer: it's a dynamic property and [mentioned in API doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html) as well, And other sub-questions are explained earlier***

Comment: Ok, I understand. But what if I want to keep follower cluster just as a backup cluster? I just decided to change cluster, and I want to unfollow and use follower as my primary cluster. I am expecting that it will have absolutely same settings, fields, replica conf etc... total duplicate. Is there any way to achieve that?  

Does "unfollow" operation considered as "as needed" from the first quote?

Comment: And what about settings update on leader. Does it replicate it to the follower? Which yes and which no. Cold you please give me some more examples.

Another thing related to "as needed". Let's suppose I ve sent search request to follower with newly added field, on leader document with this field exists, and on follower does not, how it knows how to retrieve it?

Comment: @liotur sorry for the dealy in response, again for settings as mentioned in the docs, its on need basis, and example given by you will cause the setting changed to be updated as you are querying a new field, in this case, if its not on follower index, it will fetch the setting update, and apply it on the follower.

Comment: @liotur not sure what is your use-case, but you might want to have a look at https://opster.com/elasticsearch-multi-cluster-load-balancer/ which also compares the ES CCR with opster's MCLB, and you can setup an exploratory call to understand it more.

Comment: @liotur they also mentioned `Support for active-active mode` which is not present in ES CCR, and I am getting a feeling you are looking for it.

Comment: I understood about "on need basis". How it knows that settings need to be fetched???  What if my leader is dead, and I haven't sent any search requests to follower? How settings updates will be fetched then??? 

I updated mappings on follower, and saw that it is replicated by running api (/_settings), haven't performed any searches. The same I did with analyzers, in this case I had to close index, update settings (analyzer) and open index again. After some time I saw that follower replicated this change also. 

So I still don't understand your answer till the end, sorry.

Comment: I updated mappings on leader*** (not on follower)

Comment: @liotur did you check the logs when your mappings when updated on follower?? maybe running `/_settings` will cause to fetch the updated settings from leader, but way to verify is by checking the elasticsearch logs.

Comment: Yes, now looking at the logs of the follower after updating mapping of the leader. without performing /_settings or /_mappings

and I can see in logs that mapping is replicated. but after some 20-30 secs for some reason...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225577/discussion-between-elasticsearch-ninja-and-liotur).